# Detecting letters in file A-Z then AA-ZZ

Tags: c, algorithm

My question is a rather involved one.. I am trying to create a program that will read input from stdin (console) or from a file, it will then detect the number of occurrences of each letter and each letter pair, the output will go to a comma separated value (output.csv) file or a formatted text file (with option -c)

I want to have it detect AA-ZZ where ab =/= ba
This means the output .csv will have 704 lines.
The first value will be the letter or letter-pair. The second value is total of that letter found, the third is the percentage of total letters that this specific letter or letter-pair accounts for.

Example .csv file

```
301108,"letters"
"a",23858,7.92340
"b",5017,1.66618
"c",6697,2.22412
"d",15027,4.99057
"e",36243,12.03654
"f",6113,2.03017
"g",6699,2.22478
"h",19838,6.58833
"i",19165,6.36483
"j",662,0.21985
"k",3070,1.01957
"l",12294,4.08292
"m",7309,2.42737
"n",20475,6.79989
"o",23600,7.83772
"p",4825,1.60241
"q",180,0.05978
"r",15584,5.17555
"s",18060,5.99785
"t",29362,9.75132
"u",9107,3.02450
"v",2433,0.80802
"w",8111,2.69372
"x",412,0.13683
"y",6809,2.26131
"z",158,0.05247
228914,"letter-pairs"
"aa",0,0.00000
"ab",391,0.17081
"ac",806,0.35210
"ad",1261,0.55086
"ae",1,0.00044
"af",200,0.08737
"ag",483,0.21100
"ah",19,0.00830
"ai",1152,0.50325
"aj",6,0.00262
"ak",346,0.15115
"al",1438,0.62818
"am",528,0.23065
"an",5387,2.35329
"ao",8,0.00349
"ap",369,0.16120
"aq",0,0.00000
"ar",1920,0.83874
"as",2409,1.05236
"at",3019,1.31884
"au",313,0.13673
"av",464,0.20270
"aw",392,0.17124
"ax",7,0.00306
"ay",974,0.42549
"az",30,0.01311
"ba",324,0.14154
"bb",73,0.03189
"bc",0,0.00000
"bd",3,0.00131
"be",1537,0.67143
"bf",0,0.00000
"bg",0,0.00000
"bh",0,0.00000
"bi",153,0.06684
"bj",11,0.00481
"bk",0,0.00000
"bl",480,0.20969
"bm",2,0.00087
"bn",1,0.00044
"bo",948,0.41413
"bp",0,0.00000
"bq",0,0.00000
"br",294,0.12843
"bs",45,0.01966
"bt",17,0.00743
"bu",780,0.34074
"bv",0,0.00000
"bw",2,0.00087
"bx",0,0.00000
"by",292,0.12756
"bz",0,0.00000
"ca",808,0.35297
"cb",0,0.00000
"cc",95,0.04150
"cd",4,0.00175
"ce",921,0.40233
"cf",0,0.00000
"cg",0,0.00000
"ch",1183,0.51679
"ci",257,0.11227
"cj",0,0.00000
"ck",1087,0.47485
"cl",264,0.11533
"cm",0,0.00000
"cn",10,0.00437
"co",1120,0.48927
"cp",0,0.00000
"cq",5,0.00218
"cr",287,0.12537
"cs",10,0.00437
"ct",325,0.14197
"cu",229,0.10004
"cv",0,0.00000
"cw",0,0.00000
"cx",0,0.00000
"cy",16,0.00699
"cz",0,0.00000
"da",367,0.16032
"db",10,0.00437
"dc",3,0.00131
"dd",122,0.05330
"de",1298,0.56703
"df",16,0.00699
"dg",66,0.02883
"dh",2,0.00087
"di",779,0.34030
"dj",0,0.00000
"dk",3,0.00131
"dl",148,0.06465
"dm",23,0.01005
"dn",189,0.08256
"do",1011,0.44165
"dp",4,0.00175
"dq",2,0.00087
"dr",353,0.15421
"ds",249,0.10877
"dt",1,0.00044
"du",104,0.04543
"dv",33,0.01442
"dw",2,0.00087
"dx",0,0.00000
"dy",256,0.11183
"dz",0,0.00000
"ea",1852,0.80904
"eb",70,0.03058
"ec",660,0.28832
"ed",3495,1.52677
"ee",1093,0.47747
"ef",301,0.13149
"eg",204,0.08912
"eh",56,0.02446
"ei",346,0.15115
"ej",3,0.00131
"ek",34,0.01485
"el",1346,0.58799
"em",639,0.27914
"en",2680,1.17075
"eo",57,0.02490
"ep",358,0.15639
"eq",18,0.00786
"er",4790,2.09249
"es",2117,0.92480
"et",976,0.42636
"eu",7,0.00306
"ev",651,0.28439
"ew",297,0.12974
"ex",240,0.10484
"ey",836,0.36520
"ez",12,0.00524
"fa",377,0.16469
"fb",3,0.00131
"fc",0,0.00000
"fd",0,0.00000
"fe",536,0.23415
"ff",352,0.15377
"fg",0,0.00000
"fh",1,0.00044
"fi",444,0.19396
"fj",0,0.00000
"fk",0,0.00000
"fl",200,0.08737
"fm",0,0.00000
"fn",6,0.00262
"fo",1112,0.48577
"fp",0,0.00000
"fq",0,0.00000
"fr",351,0.15333
"fs",15,0.00655
"ft",251,0.10965
"fu",287,0.12537
"fv",0,0.00000
"fw",2,0.00087
"fx",0,0.00000
"fy",8,0.00349
"fz",0,0.00000
"ga",456,0.19920
"gb",0,0.00000
"gc",0,0.00000
"gd",2,0.00087
"ge",752,0.32851
"gf",0,0.00000
"gg",111,0.04849
"gh",989,0.43204
"gi",280,0.12232
"gj",0,0.00000
"gk",0,0.00000
"gl",214,0.09348
"gm",9,0.00393
"gn",59,0.02577
"go",642,0.28045
"gp",0,0.00000
"gq",0,0.00000
"gr",450,0.19658
"gs",189,0.08256
"gt",14,0.00612
"gu",100,0.04368
"gv",0,0.00000
"gw",1,0.00044
"gx",0,0.00000
"gy",7,0.00306
"gz",0,0.00000
"ha",2977,1.30049
"hb",16,0.00699
"hc",0,0.00000
"hd",1,0.00044
"he",9214,4.02509
"hf",4,0.00175
"hg",0,0.00000
"hh",2,0.00087
"hi",2805,1.22535
"hj",0,0.00000
"hk",0,0.00000
"hl",13,0.00568
"hm",34,0.01485
"hn",13,0.00568
"ho",1320,0.57664
"hp",0,0.00000
"hq",0,0.00000
"hr",236,0.10310
"hs",21,0.00917
"ht",697,0.30448
"hu",533,0.23284
"hv",0,0.00000
"hw",3,0.00131
"hx",0,0.00000
"hy",137,0.05985
"hz",0,0.00000
"ia",119,0.05198
"ib",93,0.04063
"ic",606,0.26473
"id",1157,0.50543
"ie",570,0.24900
"if",496,0.21668
"ig",722,0.31540
"ih",0,0.00000
"ii",42,0.01835
"ij",0,0.00000
"ik",151,0.06596
"il",1063,0.46437
"im",1087,0.47485
"in",5058,2.20956
"io",569,0.24856
"ip",169,0.07383
"iq",6,0.00262
"ir",759,0.33157
"is",2164,0.94533
"it",3017,1.31796
"iu",9,0.00393
"iv",370,0.16163
"iw",0,0.00000
"ix",35,0.01529
"iy",0,0.00000
"iz",66,0.02883
"ja",41,0.01791
"jb",0,0.00000
"jc",0,0.00000
"jd",0,0.00000
"je",40,0.01747
"jf",0,0.00000
"jg",0,0.00000
"jh",0,0.00000
"ji",32,0.01398
"jj",0,0.00000
"jk",0,0.00000
"jl",0,0.00000
"jm",0,0.00000
"jn",0,0.00000
"jo",248,0.10834
"jp",0,0.00000
"jq",0,0.00000
"jr",0,0.00000
"js",0,0.00000
"jt",0,0.00000
"ju",301,0.13149
"jv",0,0.00000
"jw",0,0.00000
"jx",0,0.00000
"jy",0,0.00000
"jz",0,0.00000
"ka",6,0.00262
"kb",3,0.00131
"kc",2,0.00087
"kd",1,0.00044
"ke",844,0.36870
"kf",26,0.01136
"kg",0,0.00000
"kh",0,0.00000
"ki",286,0.12494
"kj",0,0.00000
"kk",0,0.00000
"kl",68,0.02971
"km",0,0.00000
"kn",287,0.12537
"ko",81,0.03538
"kp",0,0.00000
"kq",0,0.00000
"kr",2,0.00087
"ks",141,0.06160
"kt",2,0.00087
"ku",4,0.00175
"kv",0,0.00000
"kw",6,0.00262
"kx",0,0.00000
"ky",152,0.06640
"kz",0,0.00000
"la",1087,0.47485
"lb",9,0.00393
"lc",10,0.00437
"ld",896,0.39141
"le",1955,0.85403
"lf",251,0.10965
"lg",4,0.00175
"lh",8,0.00349
"li",1160,0.50674
"lj",0,0.00000
"lk",113,0.04936
"ll",1987,0.86801
"lm",64,0.02796
"ln",19,0.00830
"lo",1030,0.44995
"lp",40,0.01747
"lq",0,0.00000
"lr",4,0.00175
"ls",230,0.10047
"lt",172,0.07514
"lu",157,0.06858
"lv",55,0.02403
"lw",72,0.03145
"lx",0,0.00000
"ly",981,0.42855
"lz",0,0.00000
"ma",838,0.36608
"mb",148,0.06465
"mc",4,0.00175
"md",0,0.00000
"me",1834,0.80117
"mf",41,0.01791
"mg",0,0.00000
"mh",0,0.00000
"mi",597,0.26080
"mj",0,0.00000
"mk",0,0.00000
"ml",8,0.00349
"mm",89,0.03888
"mn",29,0.01267
"mo",714,0.31191
"mp",293,0.12800
"mq",0,0.00000
"mr",65,0.02839
"ms",318,0.13892
"mt",3,0.00131
"mu",243,0.10615
"mv",0,0.00000
"mw",0,0.00000
"mx",0,0.00000
"my",167,0.07295
"mz",0,0.00000
"na",223,0.09742
"nb",4,0.00175
"nc",553,0.24158
"nd",4516,1.97279
"ne",1596,0.69721
"nf",61,0.02665
"ng",2782,1.21530
"nh",9,0.00393
"ni",554,0.24201
"nj",90,0.03932
"nk",173,0.07557
"nl",149,0.06509
"nm",6,0.00262
"nn",103,0.04500
"no",1466,0.64042
"np",12,0.00524
"nq",23,0.01005
"nr",6,0.00262
"ns",509,0.22235
"nt",2310,1.00911
"nu",112,0.04893
"nv",40,0.01747
"nw",20,0.00874
"nx",10,0.00437
"ny",356,0.15552
"nz",3,0.00131
"oa",175,0.07645
"ob",147,0.06422
"oc",178,0.07776
"od",507,0.22148
"oe",252,0.11009
"of",1653,0.72211
"og",120,0.05242
"oh",128,0.05592
"oi",230,0.10047
"oj",1,0.00044
"ok",423,0.18479
"ol",725,0.31671
"om",1924,0.84049
"on",2891,1.26292
"oo",1207,0.52727
"op",345,0.15071
"oq",9,0.00393
"or",2181,0.95276
"os",486,0.21231
"ot",1103,0.48184
"ou",3592,1.56915
"ov",339,0.14809
"ow",1425,0.62250
"ox",23,0.01005
"oy",333,0.14547
"oz",9,0.00393
"pa",413,0.18042
"pb",3,0.00131
"pc",0,0.00000
"pd",0,0.00000
"pe",918,0.40102
"pf",4,0.00175
"pg",0,0.00000
"ph",39,0.01704
"pi",388,0.16950
"pj",0,0.00000
"pk",3,0.00131
"pl",439,0.19178
"pm",3,0.00131
"pn",0,0.00000
"po",579,0.25293
"pp",338,0.14765
"pq",0,0.00000
"pr",536,0.23415
"ps",99,0.04325
"pt",219,0.09567
"pu",164,0.07164
"pv",0,0.00000
"pw",3,0.00131
"px",0,0.00000
"py",28,0.01223
"pz",0,0.00000
"qa",0,0.00000
"qb",0,0.00000
"qc",0,0.00000
"qd",0,0.00000
"qe",0,0.00000
"qf",0,0.00000
"qg",0,0.00000
"qh",0,0.00000
"qi",0,0.00000
"qj",0,0.00000
"qk",0,0.00000
"ql",0,0.00000
"qm",0,0.00000
"qn",0,0.00000
"qo",0,0.00000
"qp",0,0.00000
"qq",0,0.00000
"qr",0,0.00000
"qs",0,0.00000
"qt",0,0.00000
"qu",180,0.07863
"qv",0,0.00000
"qw",0,0.00000
"qx",0,0.00000
"qy",0,0.00000
"qz",0,0.00000
"ra",896,0.39141
"rb",53,0.02315
"rc",159,0.06946
"rd",469,0.20488
"re",3957,1.72860
"rf",53,0.02315
"rg",96,0.04194
"rh",19,0.00830
"ri",1096,0.47878
"rj",0,0.00000
"rk",158,0.06902
"rl",173,0.07557
"rm",179,0.07820
"rn",393,0.17168
"ro",1391,0.60765
"rp",96,0.04194
"rq",0,0.00000
"rr",277,0.12101
"rs",671,0.29312
"rt",614,0.26822
"ru",226,0.09873
"rv",57,0.02490
"rw",37,0.01616
"rx",0,0.00000
"ry",620,0.27084
"rz",0,0.00000
"sa",899,0.39272
"sb",14,0.00612
"sc",330,0.14416
"sd",15,0.00655
"se",1837,0.80248
"sf",35,0.01529
"sg",9,0.00393
"sh",1172,0.51198
"si",779,0.34030
"sj",2,0.00087
"sk",99,0.04325
"sl",248,0.10834
"sm",146,0.06378
"sn",82,0.03582
"so",1022,0.44646
"sp",451,0.19702
"sq",15,0.00655
"sr",1,0.00044
"ss",651,0.28439
"st",2202,0.96193
"su",504,0.22017
"sv",0,0.00000
"sw",125,0.05461
"sx",0,0.00000
"sy",55,0.02403
"sz",0,0.00000
"ta",774,0.33812
"tb",5,0.00218
"tc",208,0.09086
"td",1,0.00044
"te",2166,0.94621
"tf",25,0.01092
"tg",0,0.00000
"th",9263,4.04650
"ti",1533,0.66968
"tj",0,0.00000
"tk",0,0.00000
"tl",475,0.20750
"tm",25,0.01092
"tn",37,0.01616
"to",3522,1.53857
"tp",1,0.00044
"tq",0,0.00000
"tr",677,0.29574
"ts",733,0.32021
"tt",555,0.24245
"tu",392,0.17124
"tv",0,0.00000
"tw",200,0.08737
"tx",0,0.00000
"ty",267,0.11664
"tz",1,0.00044
"ua",101,0.04412
"ub",121,0.05286
"uc",567,0.24769
"ud",204,0.08912
"ue",166,0.07252
"uf",103,0.04500
"ug",472,0.20619
"uh",0,0.00000
"ui",144,0.06291
"uj",0,0.00000
"uk",2,0.00087
"ul",941,0.41107
"um",205,0.08955
"un",1200,0.52421
"uo",23,0.01005
"up",577,0.25206
"uq",0,0.00000
"ur",1040,0.45432
"us",969,0.42330
"ut",1429,0.62425
"uu",0,0.00000
"uv",23,0.01005
"uw",1,0.00044
"ux",2,0.00087
"uy",7,0.00306
"uz",20,0.00874
"va",129,0.05635
"vb",0,0.00000
"vc",0,0.00000
"vd",0,0.00000
"ve",1899,0.82957
"vf",0,0.00000
"vg",0,0.00000
"vh",0,0.00000
"vi",304,0.13280
"vj",0,0.00000
"vk",0,0.00000
"vl",0,0.00000
"vm",0,0.00000
"vn",0,0.00000
"vo",66,0.02883
"vp",0,0.00000
"vq",0,0.00000
"vr",0,0.00000
"vs",0,0.00000
"vt",0,0.00000
"vu",3,0.00131
"vv",0,0.00000
"vw",0,0.00000
"vx",0,0.00000
"vy",15,0.00655
"vz",0,0.00000
"wa",2115,0.92393
"wb",2,0.00087
"wc",1,0.00044
"wd",18,0.00786
"we",1168,0.51024
"wf",46,0.02009
"wg",0,0.00000
"wh",1155,0.50456
"wi",1177,0.51417
"wj",0,0.00000
"wk",4,0.00175
"wl",36,0.01573
"wm",0,0.00000
"wn",337,0.14722
"wo",813,0.35516
"wp",0,0.00000
"wq",0,0.00000
"wr",46,0.02009
"ws",100,0.04368
"wt",4,0.00175
"wu",1,0.00044
"wv",0,0.00000
"ww",1,0.00044
"wx",0,0.00000
"wy",52,0.02272
"wz",0,0.00000
"xa",33,0.01442
"xb",0,0.00000
"xc",43,0.01878
"xd",0,0.00000
"xe",34,0.01485
"xf",0,0.00000
"xg",0,0.00000
"xh",8,0.00349
"xi",45,0.01966
"xj",0,0.00000
"xk",0,0.00000
"xl",0,0.00000
"xm",0,0.00000
"xn",0,0.00000
"xo",0,0.00000
"xp",65,0.02839
"xq",0,0.00000
"xr",0,0.00000
"xs",0,0.00000
"xt",63,0.02752
"xu",5,0.00218
"xv",18,0.00786
"xw",0,0.00000
"xx",43,0.01878
"xy",0,0.00000
"xz",0,0.00000
"ya",35,0.01529
"yb",127,0.05548
"yc",5,0.00218
"yd",10,0.00437
"ye",353,0.15421
"yf",1,0.00044
"yg",1,0.00044
"yh",8,0.00349
"yi",115,0.05024
"yj",0,0.00000
"yk",0,0.00000
"yl",43,0.01878
"ym",21,0.00917
"yn",3,0.00131
"yo",1063,0.46437
"yp",4,0.00175
"yq",0,0.00000
"yr",43,0.01878
"ys",409,0.17867
"yt",97,0.04237
"yu",0,0.00000
"yv",7,0.00306
"yw",44,0.01922
"yx",0,0.00000
"yy",0,0.00000
"yz",3,0.00131
"za",8,0.00349
"zb",0,0.00000
"zc",0,0.00000
"zd",0,0.00000
"ze",96,0.04194
"zf",0,0.00000
"zg",0,0.00000
"zh",0,0.00000
"zi",7,0.00306
"zj",0,0.00000
"zk",0,0.00000
"zl",4,0.00175
"zm",0,0.00000
"zn",0,0.00000
"zo",1,0.00044
"zp",0,0.00000
"zq",0,0.00000
"zr",0,0.00000
"zs",0,0.00000
"zt",0,0.00000
"zu",0,0.00000
"zv",2,0.00087
"zw",0,0.00000
"zx",0,0.00000
"zy",10,0.00437
"zz",10,0.00437
```

Options:

-c //output in CSV format

-f  //takes input file, if not specified input is stdin

-o  //output file with results, CSV format if -c used

**Here is my main.c which I am using to get arguments**

```
//main.c

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

char opt;
char *filename_in, *filename_out;
int i, flagC=0,flagF=0,flagO=0;

while((opt = getopt(argc,argv,"cf:o:")) != -1){
    switch(opt){
    case 'c':
        flagC=1;
        break;
    case 'o':
        flagO=1;
        filename_out = optarg;
        break; //etc with all options...
```

To open file and read it, I have this function that will convert each char read to lower case, but I need to implement some function of reading chars to record how many I've recorded and the occurrences.

```
int openFile(char *filename_in)
{
    char ch;
    FILE *fp;
    int pairCount[26][26] = {{0}};
    int newch;
    int oldch = '\0';

    fp = fopen(filename_in,"r");

    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ) //prints the whole file to console in lower case
        printf("%c",tolower(ch));

    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        // get the lowercase version of the character
        newch = tolower(ch);

        // if both old and new chars are valid, update the pair count
        if ( oldch >= 'a' && oldch <= 'z' && newch >= 'a' && newch <= 'z' )
            pairCount[oldch - 'a'][newch - 'a']++;

        // keep a copy of the char for the next pair
        oldch = newch;
    }

    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) { //print 2d array aa-zz
        for (j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            printf("%c%c,%d\n",i+'a',j+'a',pairCount[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a method of printing out occurrences of characters that could be useful that I found online, but I do not know how to implement this with letter pairs...

```
void find_frequency(char s[], int count[]) {
    int c = 0;

    while (s[c] != '\0') {
        if (s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z' )
            count[s[c]-'a']++;
        c++;
    }
}
```

I suppose to make my question more concise in scope.. **How would I go about detecting letter-pairs and storing them?** I could do it with 702 if statements but that is not obviously a good way to go about it.. I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to potentially use wildcards to detect it.

*TLDR; **How would I go about detecting letter-pairs and storing them?***

I think the best way would be to read char by char and save the information in an array. I've been researching a good way to do this for 3 days and I'm getting rather frustrated. Maybe I should use a structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a two dimensional array, where the rows are indexed by the first character of a pair and the columns are indexed by the first character of a pair. So the array would be declared as

```
int pairCount[26][26] = {{0}};
```

and you need to keep track of the previous character. So

```
int oldch, newch;

oldch = '\0';    // init old char to invalid value
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
{
    // get the uppercase version of the character
    newch = toupper(ch);

    // if both old and new chars are valid, update the pair count
    if ( oldch >= 'A' && oldch <= 'Z' && newch >= 'A' && newch <= 'Z' )
        pairCount[oldch - 'A'][newch - 'A']++;

    // keep a copy of the char for the next pair
    oldch = newch;
}
```

Comment: `oldch` should be static or global.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
   printf("%c ", pairCount[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }`
Thank you for your help! I am trying to print this information although it does not seem to be working. Any ideas? Or better yet, how to print this so each one is on a new line (CSV format).

Comment: @mar10 That's pretty close, you need `printf("%c%c,%d\n",i+'A',j+'A',pairCount[i][j]);`

Comment: @user3386109 You just made me laugh out loud like a mad scientist when that console output rolled by. I changed my loops to go until < 26 so it would hit Z. It seems that all the values are coming out as 0 though, regardless if oldch is static or not.

Comment: @mar10 I just tried it on a small file, and it worked. Mostly 0s of course, but some 1s and `ER` came up twice. You can edit the question to add the code that you tried, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @user3386109 I have updated my original post, I also noticed something that could be an issue... Letter pairs in words such as `don't` won't work because the apostrophe is recorded as oldchar?

Comment: @mar10 The first `while` loop reads the whole file, so there's nothing left for the second `while` loop to read. You can combine the two loops, to print and analyze at the same time, or just remove the first `while` loop.

Comment: @mar10 As for non-letter characters, you have to decide whether `nt` is a valid pair in `don't` since they aren't actually together. If you want `nt` as a pair, then the code needs an `if` statement that decides when it's appropriate to update `oldch`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71459/discussion-between-mar10-and-user3386109).